# Is it possible to learn Wing Chun remotely?

Tags: teaching, wing-chun

I've seen a lot of Wing Chun courses like this: https://www.udemy.com/wing-chun-sil-lim-tao-module-1-know-yourself/ that promise you results by watching their videos and doing the exercises they suggest. Is it really possible to learn anything useful this way or it's just a waste of money?

My guess is that it's pretty much pointless unless you also practice sparring with a teacher.

Comment: I strongly suspect that those courses offers are similar to the thousands of [419](http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/scams/nigeria.htm) emails that offered to make me tremendously rich… Oh look, your course cost £150!

Comment: I also answered a similar question more generally here:
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/learning-grappling-without-an-instructor/4317#4317